# Disable WP Trim Function for Post Titles

Tags: wordpress

I have this code in my theme
$title_count = wp_trim_words(wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 16, ''), 16, '');

but its still triming the words to 6 and not 16

How can i simply disable the trim function for post titles via functions.php

Comment: `wp_trim_words` is used throughout core in various places, you can't disable it for just one place in the theme without suppressing it for everything else. Why is it doing trim words twice to begin with? What is $title_count supposed to be?

Comment: its a built in code within a theme and I cant reach dev. I have replaced 6 with 16 in all php files using FIND function but its still keeping it to 6 words